# How to Search for string and insert multiple string from an array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have a scenario where I need to search for string stored in array of strings and insert insert multiple strings from array.

```
# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
from   Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import re

list1 = [] 
list2 = ['cat','tiger']
list_insert = [['input', 'age'],['input', 'height']]

list1.append(['wolfgang'] + list2)
print list1 

list1.append('hello name;')
list1.append('endhello: hello')

# Wanted to insert input age, input height after hello name inside braces 
# eg output like :  hello name (input age, input height);

for lines in list1:
    re.sub(r'(hello.*), r'')
```

a. Is it something like I need to do like line.startswith("hello") and do a for loop of the array list_insert to add the variables ? Any other better way to quickly add ? like reg exp ? Please provide your comments.

```
EDIT/UPDATE: Array Values
//===============================================================
// File Name        : <USER_NAME>  
// Desctiption      :
// Name             : <CREATE_NAME>
// File Created     : <CREATE_DATE>
//===============================================================

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// User Name            : <USER_NAME>
// User Desctiption     : 
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

hello <USER_NAME>;
 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 // User Details Instantiation 
 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
endhello: <USER_NAME>



EDIT/UPDATE: Updated Array Values after edit.
    //===============================================================
    // File Name        : bruno  
    // Desctiption      :
    // Name             : <CREATE_NAME>
    // File Created     : <CREATE_DATE>
    //===============================================================

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // User Name            : bruno
    // User Desctiption     : 
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    hello bruno (input age, input height);
     //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     // User Details Instantiation 
     //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    endhello: bruno
```

Comment: Hard to understand, what you want. Whisch are the strings sotred in arry, and which is the array from which you want to insert multiple strings. Perhaps you meant "for item in list_insert: do something"?

Comment: list_insert contains the string to be inserted. And I wanted to insert them after the hello name is found in a particular line.  If you see the eg: hello name (input age, input height); needs to be inserted.

Comment: does this help?  print( 'hello name( {}, {} )'.format(' '.join(list_insert[0]), ' '.join(list_insert[1])) )

Comment: Printing the name is fine but the list1 will contain more number of lines as strings.. I need to search for the string starting with hello.*  and replace with hello <anyname> (insert the array content);

Comment: For me it seems that you try to solve a simple problem in a complicated way. So I would like you to explain a bit more your requirements.

Comment: a. Have an array, where I have read a file and stored the lines in the array as show up in edit.
b. So I am trying to cycle throw the lines of array and find if the line starts with name like hello <USER_NAME>; , then I need to insert some elements from different array in front of the USER_NAME. This user name will be replaced with a different name in the array. 
Eg:  hello bruno (input age, input height);
        endhello: bruno

Comment: Still not clear, what are the requirements: You want to read a file in order to control your output which asks a user for some information? Does the file contain "hello bruno?"

Comment: @Humbalan No Worries I got it working !

Answer (score 0):

Got It working as per my requirement. Just posting for other's reference !

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
from   Tkinter import *

global tmp

tmp = None
list1 = [] 
list_insert = [['input', 'age'],['input', 'height'], ['input', 'size']]

list1.append('//===============================================================')
list1.append('// File Name        : bruno')  
list1.append('// Desctiption      :')
list1.append('// Name             : <CREATE_NAME>')
list1.append('// File Created     : <CREATE_DATE>')
list1.append('//===============================================================')
list1.append(' ')
list1.append('//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
list1.append('// User Name            : bruno')
list1.append('// User Desctiption     : ')
list1.append('//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
list1.append(' ')
list1.append('hello bruno ;')
list1.append(' //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
list1.append(' // User Details Instantiation ')
list1.append(' //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
list1.append('endhello: bruno')

list_final = []

# Wanted to insert input age, input height after hello name inside braces 
# eg output like :  hello name (input age, input height);

for lines in list1:
    if lines.startswith("hello "):
        #print( 'hello name( {}, {} )'.format(' '.join(list_insert[0]), ' '.join(list_insert[1])) )
        # if (re.search(r'hello.',lines)):
        tmp = lines.split()
        numelem = len(list_insert)
        for i in range (numelem):
            if i == 0:
                tmpstr = (list_insert[i][0]+' '+list_insert[i][1]+')')
            elif i == numelem-1:
                tmpstr = ('('+list_insert[i][0]+' '+list_insert[i][1]+',')
            else:
                tmpstr = (list_insert[i][0]+' '+list_insert[i][1]+',')
            tmp.insert(2,tmpstr)
        list_final.append(' '.join(tmp)) 
    else:
        list_final.append(lines)      

hello_file_ptr = open("hello_file", "w")

for lines in list_final:
    #hello_file_ptr.write(lines)
    print lines
```

**Output:**

```
//===============================================================
// File Name        : bruno
// Desctiption      :
// Name             : <CREATE_NAME>
// File Created     : <CREATE_DATE>
//===============================================================

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// User Name            : bruno
// User Desctiption     : 
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

hello bruno (input size, input height, input age) ;
 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 // User Details Instantiation 
 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
endhello: bruno
```